# SSIS - Native OLE DB - Multiple Steps

Tags: database, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, ole

I have Visual Studio 2008
The DB is SQL Server 2008 R2
The steps to reproduce the error are:

1. Create new SSIS Package
2. Create Native OLE DB\Microsoft Jet 4.0 OLE DB Provider
3. Create SQL Task and config:

   - Resulset: None
   - Connection Type: OLE DB
   - Connection: Connection created ant 2
   - SQL Source Type: Direct Input
   - SQLStatements: SELECT 1 FROM table

When I run this package the following error apears:

```
SSIS package "Package.dtsx" starting.
Warning: 0x0 at SQL_Q_Mensual: Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. 
         Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.
Warning: 0x0 at SQL_Q_Mensual: Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. 
         Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.
SSIS package "Package.dtsx" finished: Success.
```

and if a use a ".Net Providers for OleDb\Microsoft Jet 4.0 OLE DB Provider" the package don't generate error.

I read a lot of notes on Internet but I don't know how to resolve this. I want to use Native OLD db and not the .net Provider.

Best regards, sorry because my poor english.

Walter

Comment: Using Microsoft Jet 4.0 OLE DB Provider would indicate that you are trying to read an excel file or access database.  Which is it?  How has the connection string been configured in the OLEDB connection?  Does testing the connection in the connection manager return any errors?

Comment: I am connectiong to a Access database. The connection string was configured automatically like 'Data Source=\\server\share\databse.mdb;Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;'
On the testing conection the conection is susessfull
Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

This is often a datatype problem. Make sure you are passing valid datatypes to whatever is going on in the database. For example, check that you are not passing a NULL or empty string value to a column that doesn't accept them (either manually defined or, say, a DATETIME column). Make sure that all VARCHAR lengths and numeric bounds are adhered to. Make sure that you SELECT column1, column2, columns3 instead of using SELECT *

Note: 64-bit SQL Server cannot use Jet, there is no 64-bit OLEDB provider for Jet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But when I execute the following query: `Select 1 from Table` with the configuration: `Resulset: None`, I got the error I mencioned. So I don't think this is a datatype problem in that case.

Comment: I am in a 64-bit SQL but I set the project to compile on 32 bits.
The thing is that the error apear but the work is done.